# Open Angular project with different browser?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to open up an Angular project with a different browser than the default one?
Currently I need IE as default, but I want to open Angular projects with Chrome. Something easy from the terminal (like ng s -o -browser chrome)?

Answer (score 0):

**There is not such thing!!!**

However, you can configure the debug section (as explained in links below) to open the app in chrome, edge or firefox.

Both, ng serve and vscode(debug mode), you can achieve something similar.

See this links:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57lzJmGR8U8&ab_channel=Pixelpro
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`ng serve --browser` to open the default browser

`ng serve --browser=firefox` to open a specific browser

You can check it from [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1245).

Comment: If im not wrong, -browser is an option to target a project to open.

Comment: you can check the link provided :)

Comment: @jess ...and you will get a `Unknown option: '--browser'`

Comment: @jess the link shows a feature request to include in future versions of angular, not an actual option

Comment: It is a suggestion to pull request @jess